# How do I correctly write the syntax for performing and plotting a for loop operation?

Tags: python-3.x, function, for-loop, jupyter-notebook, pythonplotter

I am trying to create a for loop which uses a defined function (B_lambda) and takes in values of wavelength and temperature to produce values of intensity. i.e. I want the loop to take the function B_lambda and to run through every value within my listed wavelength range for each temperature in the temperature list. Then I want to plot the results. I am not very good with the syntax and have tried many ways but nothing is producing what I need and I am mostly getting errors. I have no idea how to use a for loop to plot and all online sources that I have checked out have not helped me with using a defined function in a for loop. I will put my latest code that seems to have the least errors down below with the error message:

````
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from astropy import units as u
import scipy.constants
%matplotlib inline

#Importing constants to use.
h = scipy.constants.h
c = scipy.constants.c
k = scipy.constants.k

wavelengths= np.arange(1000,30000)*1.e-10
temperature=[3000,4000,5000,6000]

for lam in wavelengths:
    for T in temperature:
        B_lambda = ((2*h*c**2)/(lam**5))*((1)/(np.exp((h*c)/(lam*k*T))-1))
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(wavelengths,B_lambda)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-73b866241c49> in <module>
     17         B_lambda = ((2*h*c**2)/(lam**5))*((1)/(np.exp((h*c)/(lam*k*T))-1))
     18         plt.figure()
---> 19         plt.plot(wavelengths,B_lambda)
     20 
     21 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in plot(scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   2787     return gca().plot(
   2788         *args, scalex=scalex, scaley=scaley, **({"data": data} if data
-> 2789         is not None else {}), **kwargs)
   2790 
   2791 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in plot(self, scalex, scaley, data, *args, **kwargs)
   1663         """
   1664         kwargs = cbook.normalize_kwargs(kwargs, mlines.Line2D._alias_map)
-> 1665         lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
   1666         for line in lines:
   1667             self.add_line(line)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    223                 this += args[0],
    224                 args = args[1:]
--> 225             yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
    226 
    227     def get_next_color(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _plot_args(self, tup, kwargs)
    389             x, y = index_of(tup[-1])
    390 
--> 391         x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
    392 
    393         if self.command == 'plot':

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in _xy_from_xy(self, x, y)
    268         if x.shape[0] != y.shape[0]:
    269             raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension, but "
--> 270                              "have shapes {} and {}".format(x.shape, y.shape))
    271         if x.ndim > 2 or y.ndim > 2:
    272             raise ValueError("x and y can be no greater than 2-D, but have "

ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (29000,) and (1,)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to note (and this is minor) is that `astropy` is not required to run your code. So, you can simplify the import statements.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.constants
%matplotlib inline

#Importing constants to use.
h = scipy.constants.h
c = scipy.constants.c
k = scipy.constants.k


wavelengths= np.arange(1000,30000,100)*1.e-10 # here, I chose steps of 100, because plotting 29000 datapoints takes a while
temperature=[3000,4000,5000,6000]
```

Secondly, to tidy up the loop a bit, you can write a helper function, that youn call from within you loop:

```
def f(lam, T):
    return ((2*h*c**2)/(lam**5))*((1)/(np.exp((h*c)/(lam*k*T))-1))
```

now you can collect the output of your function, together with the input parameters, e.g. in a list of tuples:

```
outputs = []

for lam in wavelengths:
    for T in temperature:
        outputs.append((lam, T, f(lam, T)))
```

Since you vary both wavelength and temperature, a 3d plot makes sense:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

ax.plot(*zip(*outputs))
```

[image]

An alternative would be to display the data as an image, using colour to indicate the function output.

I am also including an alternative method to generate the data in this one. Since the function `f` can take arrays as input, you can feed one temperature at a time, and with it, all the wavelengths simultaneously.

```
# initialise output as array with proper shape
outputs = np.zeros((len(wavelengths), len(temperature)))

for i, T in enumerate(temperature):
    outputs[:,i] = f(wavelengths, T)
```

The output now is a large matrix, which you can visualise as an image:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(outputs, aspect=10e8, interpolation='none', 
          extent=[
              np.min(temperature),
              np.max(temperature),
              np.max(wavelengths),
              np.min(wavelengths)]
         )
```

[image]